# How to determine gradual change rather than "stepped" change in values

Tags: derivatives, matlab, time-series, simulink

I am running a simulation in MATLAB for an aircraft and need to ensure that my pitch angle does not radically change once an altitude command is sent. As seen in the image:

[image]

After around 140 seconds the changes to pitch angle are too drastic and need to be gradual instead of happening so quickly. What kind of pass/fail test can I run to ensure the changes to angle are gradual over time? I have the values in an array and am able to compare each. I could take the derivative and calculate the rate of change of angle but over what period of time?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information? What ideal pitch angle would you like to see? Are the wild swings due to the plane trying to self correct itself? I'd be happy to give a bit of code (may not be the same programming language but it'll give you an idea of what to do), I just need a little bit of information to go off.

Comment: @Caedmon the altitude commands should automatically adjust pitch angle according to how much it needs to increase and decrease. Right now my main goal is to write tests to ensure this is happening. Ideally the pitch angle should not be at extreme values (possibly > 45 degrees) and it should not change so drastically over a short period of time